# Get ContentElemts from ContentArea

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

We’ve setup one base template with different content area placeholders. For each newsletter we place one or multiple content elements from content builder in each each of this content areas.

I now want to save on each sendout the content elements (Id of content block) that has been placed in each content area. However I cannot find any AMPscript functions that allows me to get the Id(s) of placed content.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

use like this is By name %%=ContentAreaByName('my contents\yourcontentname')=%% if you want with ID means use like this %%=ContentArea('12345')=%%

Comment: But what is the name/id of the placeholder? I only see a “data-key” within the html code.

Comment: @ Michael H from where to get the content into the template

Comment: We drag&drop content blocks in those areas via content builder

Comment: @ Michael H use this %%=ContentArea('12345')=%% in template in one block this id means content id

Comment: click on content then go to properties and you get the id of the content